# Unable to instantiate templated class inside another class

Tags: c++, templates, exception, constructor, instantiation

I have two classes: one templated, one not. I am trying to create an instance of the templated class inside the non-templated class and the program won't compile. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I get the error 'IntelliSense: expected a type specifier' on this line in bar.h:

```
Foo<int> foo_complex(99);
```

I *can* use this syntax outside a class (see console.cpp below). I *can* use the empty constructor inside the class. What gives? How do I correctly use the non-empty constructor for Foo inside Bar?

Thanks in advance for your help. I've looked everywhere for a solution and come up empty. Example code is below. Class implementation is inline for clarity.

**foo.h**

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(int i);
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo()
{
    std::cout << "You created an instance of Foo without a value." << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(int i)
{
    std::cout << "You created an instance of Foo with int " << i << std::endl;
}
```

**bar.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "foo.h"

class Bar
{
private:
    Foo<int> foo_simple;
    Foo<int> foo_complex(99); // Error ~ IntelliSense:expected a type specifier
public:
    Bar(int i);
};

Bar::Bar(int i)
{
    std::cout << "You created an instance of Bar with int " << i << std::endl;
}
```

**console.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo<int> foo(1);
    Bar bar(2);
    std::string any = "any";

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press any key to close this window..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> any; 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize member variables in the constructor:

```
class Bar
{
private:
    Foo<int> foo_complex;
public:
    Bar(int i);
};

Bar::Bar(int i) : foo_complex(99)
{
    std::cout << "You created an instance of Bar with int " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. The other options on the page are probably also good but they don't work for the most recent Visual Studio compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use brace-initialization:

```
Foo<int> foo_complex{99};
```

C++11 allows *brace-or-equal-initializers* for inline initialization of data members, so other valid alternatives are (since `Foo<int>` is move-constructible):

```
Foo<int> foo_complex = Foo<int>(99);
```

And (since `Foo<int>` has a non-`explicit` converting constructor taking an `int`):

```
Foo<int> foo_complex = 99;
```

As in C++03, of course, you could initialize your `foo_complex` data member in the constructor's initialization list.

Comment: **Option 1**: threw 10 errors including c2511 "Bar::Bar(int) : overloaded member function not found in 'Bar'" and c2664 "Bar::Bar(const Bar&) : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'const Bar &'" along with a bunch of syntax errors (expected ';, unxpected tokens, syntax error 'public', etc.). **Option 2** and **Option 3** throw: error C2864: "'Bar::fox_complex' only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class". **Option 3:

Comment: Looks like the 'Nov 2012 CTP v120' compiler for Visual Studio is not completely compliant with C++11. These would probably all be good options with a more complete compiler.

Comment: @kseier: Yes, that seems to be the case. Probably VC11 only supports the last, C++03-style option (initialize in the constructor's initialization list)

Answer (score -1):

This is trying to declare a function:

```
Foo<int> foo_complex(99);
```

I think it's saying you need a type specifier as a parameter. You need to construct this object in the constructor, not in the class definition.

Answer (score -1):

You can't initialize an object when you declare it as a member variable, you have to do it in the containing class constructors initializer list:

```
Bar::Bar(int i)
    : foo_complex(99)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

If your compiler is new enough to support [C++11 uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization) you should be able to do it though, but with a slightly different syntax:

```
Foo<int> foo_complex{99};
```

Note the braces instead of parenthesis.